# Looking for a website with a help system/tooltips

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hey, basically I am looking to gather ideas. I am making a help system for a website. jQuery tooltips and all. I just wanted to see how others have done it to get a better direction. The only problem is I cannot think of any sites off hand that have a help system or a tooltip system. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I found this [E-help jQuery system](http://embedded-help.net/ehelp/v114/). It's more than just tooltips but it allows you to make tutorial right on the page where the user is. Might be helpful to you, if you haven't found anything else already.

Answer (score 1):

A lot websites that provide content related to online games do this. The [World of Warcraft Armory](http://www.wowarmory.com/search.xml?fl[source]=all&fl[type]=weapons&fl[subTp]=1haxe&searchType=items) is one such site. Mouse over the items in the search results to see an example; as an added bonus, it would seem they use jQuery to do it.

Comment: That is a very good one. Thank you! I just don't have a lot of time to get into forums about game sites or really...much internet surfing at all lately.

Answer (score 1):

[Resource Page 1](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/)

[Resource Page 2](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/)

Linked above are two galleries of jQuery implemented tooltip plug-ins, 45 examples in total. I would go through them and see what designs would look best given your website's theme. You could either use one of the featured plug-ins or simply use them for inspiration and mash-up a tooltip script more customized to your needs.

Comment: Yes, those are awesome. I am just looking for a website that implements a help system like that or using those tool tips. Like a fully implemented version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for tooltips, I highly recommend qTip2 http://www.craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/

It is very easy to customize, with lots of functions and most importantly, the creator is very supportive. You can also create a website tour using this, so it helps to provide the Help function you want.

Do check this out :)